# Recommend a flexible lightbox that allows an image or HTML to be used

Tags: plugins

Can anyone recommend a flexible lightbox plugin that allows the popup lighbox to use an image and/or HTML?

I want to overlay some sort of help instructions on top of my WP home page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any of the folowing should do just fine:

- [Overlay](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/overlay/)
- [FancyBox for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/)
- [Simple Lightbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-lightbox/)
- [WP Multibox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multibox/)
- [TopUp Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/topup-plus/)

and my personal favorite [Highslide 4 WordPress *reloaded*](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/highslide-4-wordpress-reloaded/)

Comment: Cool thanks! I was using "Flexible Lightbox" but it stopped working for me a few WP revisions ago.